# How to generate form main GUI another GUI to allow user sets some parameter for the main GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for a few days that I couldn't find in my search.
I have a main GUI with lots of frames, buttons and labels.
A button (parameter) in this GUI is for the user to change the parameters for the main GUI.
I found out that I have to use Toplevel() to create a new GUI.
This GUI has also lots of frames, buttons and labels for the required parameters.
Since the main GUI has lots of widgets and also the second GUI for the parameters as well, it becomes very confusing when I write all the widgets for the second GUI in the definition of Toplevel().
Therefore, I have two Python scripts, each of which creates a self-sufficient GUI. When I run them individually, I have two independent GUIs.
I don't know how I only have to specify the name of the Python script for the parameters in the function in the main GUI, where an instance of Toplevel () is generated, in order to make my program modular and clear.
Any help is appreciated.
Mohsen

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your requirement, but from what I have understood you might be looking for something like this

Main script

```py
from tkinter import *
from config import Config

root=Tk()

label=Label(root,text='Sample')
label.pack()
button=Button(root,text='Configure',command=lambda:Config(root))
button.pack(padx=100)

root.mainloop()
```

`config.py`

```py
from tkinter import *

class Config(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        cl_label=Label(self,text='Label Color')
        cl_label.pack()
        self.cl_entry=Entry(self)
        self.cl_entry.pack()
        cl_button=Button(self,text='Update',command=self._change_label_color)
        cl_button.pack(padx=100)

    def _change_label_color(self):
        child_widgets=self.master.winfo_children()
        color=self.cl_entry.get()
        for child in child_widgets:
            if isinstance(child,Label):
                child.config(bg=color)
```

**UPDATE**

`config.py` without OOP

```py
from tkinter import *

def config(parent):
    global toplevel
    toplevel=Toplevel(parent)
    cl_label=Label(toplevel,text='Label Color')
    cl_label.pack()
    cl_entry=Entry(toplevel)
    cl_entry.pack()
    cl_button=Button(toplevel,text='Update',
        command=lambda: _change_label_color(cl_entry.get()))
    cl_button.pack(padx=100)

def _change_label_color(color):
    child_widgets=toplevel.master.winfo_children()
    for child in child_widgets:
        if isinstance(child,Label):
            child.config(bg=color)
```

Changes in the main script

`from config import config` and `command=lambda:config(root)`

Comment: I think that is some how what I want.

Comment: But the problem is that I am not so familiar with the class method.
Du you have a version for config.py without class?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I understand now much better.  That is what I wanted.  My problem is solved.